# Accessing WebApi with HMAC authentication from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am going through some problem in accessing WebApi(asp.net webapi 2). Secnario is on my side i need to access api's method 'GetDetails'(https://localhost/api/GetDetails) from my angularjs coding, but api is protected with HMAC authentication. I have key and id which is required for authentication. How can i call to that api from angularjs web app?